# Powershell filter to most recent by time

Tags: powershell, rest, filter

I need to use both the alias and createdAt properties to select the correct tinyId value so that I can make a post call. I need to select the tinyId of an alert that was created no more than than 5 min ago since my next post call is made almost immediately after alert creation. The time format returned is in UTC, so if I run a get-date I'm thinking I have to first convert it to UTC in order to compare to the date received in the api call.

I can easily filter by the alias alone and select the tinyId...the part I'm lost on is filtering by the alias AND the createdAt time. I need to make sure it is made within the last 5 minutes. Not any greater than that or it will grab multiple alerts, so using the simple -le doesn't work.

Here is what the object returned looks like from the api call

```
seen           : True
id             : 059770c5
tinyId         : 734
alias          : 123456789
message        : Incoming call 
status         : closed
acknowledged   : True
isSeen         : True
tags           : {}
snoozed        : False
count          : 1
lastOccurredAt : 12/27/2019 8:03:20 PM
createdAt      : 12/27/2019 8:03:20 PM
updatedAt      : 12/27/2019 9:31:44 PM
```

$request is the data returned in the api call

```
$currentDateTime = Get-Date
$a = $currentDateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")

$filterAlertID = $request.data | 
Where-Object {($_.alias -eq "123456789") -and ($_.createdAt -le $a)} | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty tinyId
```

Comment: The problem is likely datatypes.  The datatype returned by the REST API is serialized and therefore lost all of it's underlying object-specific members.  You need to convert the likely dates returned by the API as strings back to datetime objects.  I just tested on the dates and they will statically cast:  [datetime]'12/27/2019 8:03:20 PM'.  After you do that, you can do datetime object based comparisons accurately.

Comment: You need to compare **Date objects**, not **strings**. Remove the `ToString` stuff from the date in `$a` and get the createdAt as real date. `[datetime]::ParseExact($_.createdAt,"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt",[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)`